# smart capture - info pushed to all subscribers - if yes, how?

Tags: marketing-cloud, smart-capture

So we are thinking of implementing CliodPages in our company.

Wondering if the form - Smart Capture - does it save the collected info in the All Subscribers?

I found this info on [`Smart Caputre`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_smart_capture.htm&type=5), but it's not entirely clear to me:

> When a lead completes the form on the landing page and clicks the Submit button, the Smart Capture form automatically adds the information to the subscriber list, data extension, or outside data source such as an integrated CRM system.

But how do we choose the place?

Answer (score 3):

All Subscribers list is not meant to store data like form submissions. The primary purpose of All subscribers list is to store the status of your subscribers (active, bounced, unsubscribed), you can read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_all_subscribers_list.htm&type=5

Data Extensions are the best way to work with Smart Capture forms.
Create a data extension first, with all necessary fields (all fields which you want to be visible on your form), and then in Web Studio, insert Smart Capture form onto your landing page and link it with your data extension. All data submitted via the form will land there.